# How to do Multiple Biddings on Multiple Items in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do Multiple Biddings on Multiple Items for different suppliers in Jmeter... Can any one help me...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have an auction site and want to place multiple bids on multiple items for different suppliers.

Start by recording ONE bid on ONE item for ONE supplier.  There are lots of tutorials for helping with recording.

After you've recorded this scenario, you want to add parametrization to the script.  I would recommend by starting with multiple items for a single supplier.  There are lots of ways you can do this.  You can give Jmeter a CSV data file to read, or scrape the page. Personally, I would do the following:

```
- Load Page that shows all items for a specific supplier
-- Do a regular expression extractor to get ALL items on the page
- FOR EACH item (loop)
-- Bid on item
```

Then I would make the supplier dynamic. Again, you can give Jmeter a CSV data file, or scrape the page. I would do this:

```
- Load page that shows all suppliers
-- Do a regular expression extractor to get ALL suppliers
- FOR EACH supplier (loop)
-- Load Page that shows all items for the supplier
--- Do a regular expression extractor to get ALL items on the page
-- FOR EACH item (loop)
--- Bid on item
```

For the multiple bid part, it would depend on how many bids you want, and which users make the bid.  Is it the same user making the bids? Or do different users need to make the bids?

If it's the same user, you could add a loop to "Bid on the item" and od it as many times as needed.

If it's different users, create a data file with all the users you need, then loop through the entire scenario multiple times with different users.

The user manual has some examples and lots of use tips and tricks:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate some more? When you say "Multiple Biddings" I think you're referring to something domain-specific you want to do. Perhaps if you describe first what JMeter components you are using now, an HTTP Request? SOAP/XML request, the nature of the system in question, we could help you.